# What is the flag in the clang compiler to define a macro to be used by the preprocessor?

Tags: c, clang, c-preprocessor

In the gcc compiler we can provide a macro to be used by the preprocessor in **C** using -D flag (example- `gcc -DN=10 test.c`)

What is the flag that can be used to do the same in the clang compiler?

When I give the same -D option to the clang compiler on Windows, it gives an error:

> "Directory not found."

Comment: I found a clang option that might be able to do this called -Xpreprocessor  here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html

Comment: It's also `-D`. You should post a test case and the clang version. Does `clang test.c` work or is it only `clang -DN=10 test.c` that doesn't?

Comment: @Himeshi `-Xpreprocessor` is not what you are looking for. This option is called `-D` in clang, too. In fact, POSIX specifies that the C compiler must provide the option `-D` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is the 2 comments from @cremno and @FUZxxl above.

The error wasn't coming from the clang compiler although it said clang error. Rather it was coming from the Windows cmd which looks for a directory after the '=' sign.